# Listener when message is set in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, messages, timeout, notification

I am deleting the `mage-messages` cookie, how sometimes it's not getting deleted for iPhone Safari browser. I have even added `set timeout` for 5 sec. The issue is the notification persists on other pages too.
The reason is the `mage-messages` cookies doesn't get cleared and if it does get cleared it somehow get set even after the `5-sec timeout`.

```
 this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];

 this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

 if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

 setTimeout(function()
 {
   YX_UI_UTIL.eraseCookie("mage-messages");
 }, 5000);
```

It's not working, even after the `5-sec timeout`, I think, `mage-messages` is still getting set.

So is there any `listener` when `mage-messages` cookie is set. so that I can clear the cookie when it set even after the `5-sec timeout`.

Even when the `mage-messages` cookies are not cleared, I cleared it from the browser console while debugging and it worked. The notification messages don't persist on other pages.